# AJAX Request CORS Policy error with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, flask-cors

I'm using Flask to build a simple backoffice.
I'm trying to make some requests on client-side using AJAX, but it is always throwing me the following error:

> access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.11.0.123/...' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've already tried several solutions but none of them worked. I'm also using CORS package from flask_cors, in the following way:

```
    CORS(app, resources={r"/hardware/control/1": {"origins": "http://localhost:5000"}})
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, threaded=True)
```

However, I think that have no impact on AJAX requests since Flask app runs on server side. So here it is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://10.11.0.123/...',
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result)
            },
        });
```

I know that the destination sever is receiving the request, however I can not receive any response from the server.

Analysing the network requests, from chrome console, the request returns status: failed and Type: xhr.

My endpoint in flask is:

```
@system.route('/hardware/control/<int:device_id>')
def hardware_control(device_id):
    device = Device.query.get(device_id)
    return render_template('hardware_interaction/camera_preview.html',device=device)
```

I'm creating the app like this:

```
def create_app():
     app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
     app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')
     CORS(app, resources={r"/hardware/control/*": {"origins": "*"}})
     with app.app_context():
        return app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, threaded=True)
```

Comment: instead of `"origins": "http://localhost:5000"` try `"origins": "*"` and make sure you're hitting the endpoint specified in the `resources` property. As the one sparse answer mentioned, the issue is that your server needs to have an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set that will be returned in what is called a "preflight" or "options" request. As always, I recommend reading documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thank you for the response. It does not work. I've already tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to test that it's actually a CORS issue. This worked for me.

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    header = response.headers
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Authorization'
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, DELETE, PUT'
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've already tried it and does not work. If it's not a CORS issue what you think that could be?

Comment: Could you share your endpoint code and the whole error log that displays in chrome browser.

Comment: I've made some edits to my question for you to check. Thank you

Comment: I tested an example with my above `after_request` example. I also made a change to Ajax. I kept `url` , `type` , `contentType` and `success` and get rid of `header` , `withCredentials` and `crossDomain` and it functioned perfectly. Just one notice if you have `system` blueprint and this blueprint has a `url_prefix` you probably should added it to `CORS` resources url.

Answer (score 0):

The header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must be returned from Flask, not requested by AJAX. So it would be something like this:

```
def get_content():
    return "It works!", 200

@app.route('/')
def home():
    content, status_code = get_content()
    headers = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
    return content, status_code, headers
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding what your get_content() method is.

Comment: The `get_content` method is just a way I have to avoid writing your output, since I don't know what it is. I'll edit the answer to make it easier.

Comment: The route should render a template.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help. I already solved the problem. I was making requests to HTTP PTZ Camera  which don't let me make requests from client side (I've no idea why). So I hack the problem, and now I'm making requests to my server, and my server make the request to the camera. Here you've what I'm doing:

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/teste00',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {},
        });
```

On server side:

```
@system.route('/teste00')
def teste():
    response = requests.get('camera_url')
   return response.content
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a time from question, but i use flask-cors

To install using pip:
pip install flask flask-cors

See documentation in https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

@app.route('/ajaxcomp')
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def ajaxcomp():
    if request.is_json:
        component = request.args.get('component')
        comp_list = components.query.filter_by(SIGLA=componente).all()
        results = components_schema.dump(comp_list)
        return jsonify(results)
```

For me works fine.